# Use model attribute value in differnt views

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I an new to backbone and try to figure out how to pass a model attribute over my one page application.
I am using backbone with jquery, requirejs and underscore.

My code looks like
model:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {

    'use strict';

    var sessionCall = Backbone.Model.extend({

        url: "http://myserver/sessionCall",

        defaults: {
            APIKey: 'NULL'
        },

        initialize: function() {

            $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
                options.crossDomain ={
                    crossDomain: true
                };
                options.xhrFields = {
                    withCredentials: false
                };
            });
            return this;
        }
    });

    return sessionCall;
    });
```

Login View:

```
 define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'models/mSessionCall',
    'text!tpl/login.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, AppRouter model, tpl) {

   // var loginView = Backbone.View.extend({ //if used //return loginView; below

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            "click #clb_login":         "callLoginCheck",
            "click #clb_newAccount":    "callNewAccount"
        },

        initialize: function () {

        },

        el: $('#container'),
        render: function () {

            var template = _.template(tpl);
            this.$el.html(template());
        },

        callLoginCheck: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //Don't let this button submit the form

            var loginCheck = new model();
            //Save working version
            loginCheck.save( {
                success: function (loginCheck, data) {
                    loginCheck.set({USR_APIKey: data[0]['USR_APIKey']});
                    appRouter.navigate('home', true);
                },
                error: function(loginCheck, response) {
                    console.log('error');
                    appRouter.navigate('', true);
                }
            });
        },

        callNewAccount: function () {
            appRouter.navigate('newAccount', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Home view:

Above all is working perfect. But how do I use my USR_APIKey in different views because I need this key to be able to update/get/delete my date on my REST server.

Any ideas ?
thx

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best wayis to save your api key in some places (session or other) because if you want to get this value you have to create a login vieew every time and get this attribute in this way for example:

```
this.loginView = new LoginView();
this.loginView.model.get('APIKey');
```

Answer (score 0):

We have two familiar things from browser perspective.

- sessionStorage
- localStorage

You can make use of any of the above to store the value of USR_APIKey.

Otherwise, you have to call the LoginView() each time you need the USR_APIKey value, which is not a good practice (in terms of performance). And also to get rid of the zombie views, we close each view when the UI scope is over.

Hope this helps